# Postgresql Copy from Delimited file without Header issue. ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6.2

I run below sql statement

```
Copy table_name FROM 'File.txt' with csv delimiter '|' ;
```

Below error message is displayed

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "﻿1"

I do not have any black spaces , character or null in the data
But when I change the sql statement including "Header" ,

```
Copy table_name FROM 'File.txt' with csv delimiter '|' header;
```

It is working fine, but ignores first record as headers is enabled as true.
My data file doesn't have any headers and I need to import first record
When I provide header as false, I am seeing same error message

```
Copy table_name FROM 'File.txt' with csv delimiter '|' header false;
```

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "﻿1"

I tried changing first record to different values, but still issue remains same

Comment: try `opy table_name FROM 'File.txt' delimiter '|'` and btw - showing first two lines of your file would greatly help

Comment: Tried it, still seeing same error message

Comment: Drop the "with", try it like this: `COPY my_table FROM 'c:\file.csv' DELIMITERS '|' CSV`

Comment: @VaoTsun  

file is in below format
1|"XXX"|"ABCDE"
2|"XYZ"|"ABNAA"

Table is in below format,
Col1 (smallint)
Col2 (character varying length 50)
Col3 (Character varying length 50)

Comment: @celsoap7, thanks for your suggestion, i tried with dropping "with" still no luck :(

Comment: Please provide table definition and sample data from input file.